# How to make matlab simplify an equation before giving result

Tags: matlab

i am trying to write an equation in matlab:

```
x = 1;
y = factorial(365) ./ factorial(365-x)
```

in mathematical terms this equals to:

```
ans = 365
```

but instead of this it gives: `NaN`

i think it is because matlab doesn't do the simplification operations and calculates up and down, then it looks it is `inf/inf` and gives `NaN`. How can i change this ?

Comment: I'd add, in addition to the answers, that you're simply seeing the limitations of floating point arithmetic! For handling enormous integers, also feel free to checkout [variable precision integer arithmetic](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic) on the file exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use:

```
n = 100
x = 5

% Original
f1 = factorial(n)/factorial(n-x)
% Division friendly
f2 = prod([(x+1):n]./[1:(n-x)])*factorial(x)
```

It can deal with your input without problem (n=365, x=1).